# Replace part of a string between indexes in Java

Tags: java, string

Say I have the string `123456789`. I know that I want to replace indexes 3-5 of the string. (4, 5, and 6). Keep in mind that the replacement probably isn't 3 characters, I might want to end up with `123foobar789`.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: @ogzd No, just an idiot. Sorry about the stupid question, everyone!

Comment: The comment saying it's "ambiguous" is not appropriate.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Firstly, you cannot do it<sup>1</sup>, since a `String` is immutable in java.

However, you can create a new String object with the desired value, using the [`String#substring()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method (for example):

```
String s = "123456789";
String newString = s.substring(0, 3) + "foobar" + s.substring(3+3);
System.out.println(newString);
```

---

If you do want to achieve it efficiently, you could avoid creating some intermediate strings used by the concatinating and `substring()` method.

```
String s = "123456789";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char[] buff = s.toCharArray();
sb.append(buff , 0, 3).append("foobar");
sb.append(buff,3+3,buff.length -(3+3));
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

However, if it is not done in a very tight loop - you should probably ignore it, and stick with the first and more readable solution.

---

(1) not easily anyway, it can be done with [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) - but it should be avoided.

Comment: How about suggesting `StringBuffer.replace`

Comment: This is quite possibly the most inefficient way to accomplish this.

Comment: The question asks How it *can* be done, not about how it can be done *efficiently*. It is the most *readable* way to accomplish it, and unless this is done in a very tight loop - there is no need to optimize it for something less readable and more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that String is immutable. That immediately puts one on the right track.

Comment: Immutability is irrelevant. I'd expect a `replaceRange(int start, int length, String replacement)` method, for example, would return the updated string with the range replaced.

Answer (score 60):

Try below code. With help of StringBuffer you do replacement. [StringBuffer replace java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String))

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("123456789");

        int start = 3;
        int end = 6;
        buf.replace(start, end, "foobar"); 
        System.out.println(buf);

    }

}
```

After running above program below will be out put.

```
123foobar789
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/oXfxUE)

Answer (score 14):

If there is no repetition  of given substring then try this.

```
String s ="123456789";
s = s.replace(s.substring(3,6), "foobar");
```

If there is  repetition  of given substring then try this.

```
String s ="123123123";
s= s.substring(0,3) + "foobar" + s.substring(6,s.length());
```

Comment: It solves the problem for the example input only. What will happen for `s="123123123"` ?