# How to remove comments denoted by /* and */ in a string?

Tags: java

My task is to create a method to remove text between /* and */ in a string. This method must remove all comments in the string.

Example: 
`"The quick brown /\* and red\*/ fox jumped over the lazy dog /\*laying on the porch\*/."`
turns into
`"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.`

I've successfully managed to remove one comment by finding the index of "/*" and "*/", and creating a substring with those indexes and removing it. I created a loop that checks to see if the index for /* is not equal to one, and if it is not, it removes a comment.

However, after removing one comment, I am left with the /* and */ marks after removing it, and so the removing method I wrote does not work, because it is removing the code inside of the empty /**/ marks, and not moving on to the next comment. I've attempted to remove the comment marks by creating a substring that encompasses the comment as a whole using the previously mentioned indexes, and creating a substring that is the rest of the string, removing the comment marks in the first string, and then combining the strings together to form a whole again.

When I run the method, and the loop, it removes the first comment and its respective comment marks, but it leaves the second comment completely untouched.

```
public static String removeOneComment(String s)
{
    String start = "/*";
    String end = "*/";
    int i = s.indexOf(start);
    int i1 = s.indexOf(end);
    String s1 = s.substring(i, i1);
    s = s.replaceAll(s1, "");
    String s1s = s.substring(0, i1 + 2);
    String s1s1 = s.substring(i1 + 2);
    s1s = s1s.replaceAll("/\\*", "");
    s1s = s1s.replaceAll("\\*/", "");
    s = s1s + s1s1;
    return s;
}
public static String removeComments(String s)
{
    String start = "/*";
    String end = "*/";
    for (int i = s.indexOf(start); i != -1; i = s.indexOf(start, i + 1));;
    {
        s = removeOneComment(s);
    }
    return s;
}
```

By running this code, the result I get is "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog /*laying on the porch*/."

Original String: `"The quick brown /\*and red\*/ fox jumped over the lazy dog /\*laying on the porch\*/."`
turns into
Wanted String: `"The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use \ (escape) to prevent the formatting from going italic with the * (like so: \\*)

Comment: You're thinking too hard.  You can do this _either_ with just `.indexOf()` and `.substring()` or with just `.replaceAll()`; you don't need all three!

Comment: You can use `str.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/ ", "")` to replace all commented strings.

Comment: Santhosh: your  regex looks good exept for the trailing space. Looks to me better than the answers below.

Comment: return s.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/ ", ""); does not work at all

Comment: How do you want to handle `/*` without a corresponding `*/`? Leave it intact, terminate the string there, or throw an exception?

Answer (score 1):

You should just use this.

```
public static String removeComments(String s)
{
    return s.replaceAll("\\/\\* *\\w+ *\\*\\/", "");
}
```

Comment: that only removes the first comment

Answer (score 0):

If you can use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), then just go with a simple `String#replaceAll` using the [following](https://regex101.com/r/XqiwR9/1) which will basically remove the boundaries with everything is between.

```
(\/asterisk.*?asterisk\/)
```

If you can't use regex, just go with a simple loop, containing an `if` statement and a counter determining your boundaries. At the end, delete everything using `String#substring` beginning by the comments close to the end to not lose integrity of your counters.

Answer (score 0):

that works :) 
- I am looking for opening and trailing comment tags- `*/` and `\*`, its the reason why replacement is with offset
- as it is obvious, it's using recursive calls

Some clues taken from [Replace part of a string between indexes in Java [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14642978/replace-part-of-a-string-between-indexes-in-java)

```
public static String removeCommentsString(String input) {
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54586730/how-to-remove-comments-denoted-by-and-in-a-string
    if (input.contains("\\*") && input.contains("*/")) {
        int firstOccurenceOpen = input.indexOf("\\*");
        int firstOccurenceTrailing = input.indexOf("*/");

        input = replaceAt(firstOccurenceOpen, firstOccurenceTrailing, input);

        if (input.contains("\\*") && input.contains("*/")) {
            input= removeCommentsString(input);
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }

    return input;
}

public static String replaceAt(int startIndexIncl, int endIndexIncl, String data) {
    // -2 because space and \, +2 because /\*
    return data.substring(0, startIndexIncl - 2) + data.substring(endIndexIncl + 2, data.length());
}
```

Tests:

```
input: The quick brown /\* and red\*/ fox jumped over the lazy dog /\*laying on the porch\*/.,
 output: The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.
input: The quick brown /\* and red\*/ fox jumped....,
 output: The quick brown fox jumped....
```